# Exception not caught in multiprocessing

Tags: python, exception, multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing module for files processing in parallel, which works perfectly fine almost every time.
Also I've written that in try , except block to catch any exception.
I've come across a situation where except block doesn't catch the exception.

Since the code is huge I'm just putting relevant block which is giving problem.

```
  def reader(que, ip, start, end, filename):
  """ Reader function checks each line of the file
  and if the line contains any of the ip addresses which are
  being scanned, then it writes to its buffer.
  If the line field doesn't match date string it skips the line.
  """

  logging.info("Processing :   %s" % os.path.basename(filename))
  ip_pat = re.compile("(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\:\d+)")
  chunk = 10000000 # taking chunk of 10MB data

  buff = ""
  with bz2.BZ2File(filename,"rb", chunk) as fh: # open the compressed file
      for line in fh:
          output = []
          fields = line.split()
          try:
              ts = fields[1].strip() + "/" +fields[0]+"/"+fields[3].split("-")[0]+" "+fields[2]
              times = da.datetime.strptime(ts,"%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S")
              if times < start:
                  continue
              if times > end:
                  break
              ips = re.findall(ip_pat,line)
              if len(ips) < 3:
                  continue
              if ips[0].split(":")[0] == ip:
                  output.append(times.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
                  status = "SESSION_OPEN" if "SESSION_OPEN" in line or "CREATE" in line else "SESSION_CLOSE"
                  protocol = "TCP" if "TCP" in line else "UDP"
                  output.append(status)
                  output.append(protocol)
                  ips[1], ips[2] = ips[2], ips[1]
                  output.extend(ips)
                  res = "|".join(output)
                  buff += res + "\n"
          except IndexError, ValueError:
              continue
  logging.info("Processed  :   %s of size [ %d ]" % (os.path.basename(filename), os.path.getsize(filename)))
  if buff:
    que.put((ip,buff))
  return buff
```

And this is what is received as error.

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: time data '2/Dec/20 10:59:59' does not match format '%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S'

What I don't understand is why the exception is not caught, I've mentioned ValueError in except block.

What's the best way to get through this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the multiple exceptions as a tuple:

```
except (IndexError, ValueError):
          continue
```

The relevant doc is https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Snippet from the page:

> Note that the parentheses around this tuple are required, because except ValueError, e: was the syntax used for what is normally written as except ValueError as e: in modern Python (described below). The old syntax is still supported for backwards compatibility. This means except RuntimeError, TypeError is not equivalent to except (RuntimeError, TypeError): but to except RuntimeError as TypeError: which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks Cory. I'll give a try again with the changes mentioned.

Comment: @dsgdfg I'm not sure what you mean or why "collect garbage data" is in quotes.